# How to replace copied text from QTextEdit in clipboard?

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qclipboard

I have a QTextEdit which contains `It's test.` I want to select this text and copy it to my clipboard using Ctrl+C, but replace "test" with "good" in clipboard only.

Comment: Ali, you are member in SO for 5 yrs .. you might want to refresh on how to make good questions [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a pointer to a [`QClipboard`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qclipboard.html) called `clipboard`:

```
QString data = clipboard->text();

data.replace(QString("test"), QString("good"));

clipboard->setText(data);
```

This uses the functions [`QString::replace`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#replace-8) to modify the text of the clipboard (Accessed from [`QClipboard::text`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qclipboard.html#text)) and [`QClipboard::setText`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qclipboard.html#setText) to set the new text for the clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to use Signals/Slots to synchronize *what to change in clipboard* with what you are actually doing *in QTextEdit field* to avoid undefined behaviors and *accidentally* modifying things outside the scope of your task. in order to do that catch a `signal` emitted when you ***highlight*** this particular QTextEdit field,  that signal insures you you can copy the highlighted text `QTextEdit::copyAvailable(bool yes)` .. `yes` indicates availability of a highlighted text.

Most importantly, make sure you are accessing global clipboard only when you CTRL+C the highlighted text from your QTextEdit field, by attaching to the signal `QClipboard::dataChanged` which indicates that you copied the text ... then only modify the text.

> To test this code: write your sentence .. highlight it .. use CTRL+C
>   to copy to clipboard and its modified.

Example:
class files can look like this:

```
.h
{
private slots:
    void textSelected(bool yes);
    void changeTextCopiedToCB();

private:
    QClipboard *clipboard;
};
```

Class `.cpp`

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(this->ui->textEdit, &QTextEdit::copyAvailable, this, &MainWindow::textSelected); // emmited when you select the text
    clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
}

void MainWindow::textSelected(bool yes) // Slot called only when you select text in your field
{
    if (yes){
        qDebug() << this->ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
        connect(clipboard, &QClipboard::dataChanged, this, &MainWindow::changeTextCopiedToCB); // wait tor CTRL+C
    }
}
void MainWindow::changeTextCopiedToCB() // Once CTRL+C .. the data in clipboard changes..thats my data
{
    QString text = clipboard->text();
    text.replace(QString("test"), QString("good"));
    clipboard->setText(text);
    disconnect(clipboard, &QClipboard::dataChanged, this, &MainWindow::changeTextCopiedToCB); // after copy from this field, leave clipboard alone!
    qDebug() << clipboard->text();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to replace clipboard only when I have copied text from QTextEdit, but it replace my clipboard when the clipboard changed, although I copy text outside of my application. (I'm using X11)

Comment: Yes, without `selecting` the text inside the `QTextEdit` the clipboard is not affected .. notice also that the code `connect` the clipboard `datachanged` signal only after you `select` the text ..once you copy the text the `connect` is removed `disconnect` which means AFTER that your clipboard is not manipulated