# QClipboard's signal selectionChanged doesn't work in Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5, qt-signals

I am trying to get `selectionChanged` signal from QClipboard but it doesn't trigger when selection is changed. I've tried in Linux and it works but not in Windows 7.

P. s. `void QClipboard::dataChanged()` works well but not `void QClipboard::selectionChanged()`.

**How could I make to work `selectionChanged` in Windows 7?**

*Signal and slot connector.*

```
QObject::connect(
        qClipboard, &QClipboard::selectionChanged,
        this, &MainWindow::clipboardSelectionChanged
);
```

*Triggered method.*

```
void MainWindow::clipboardSelectionChanged() {
    qDebug() << "works";
}
```

Comment: Windows and macOS don't support selections.

Comment: Your code is using the signal `QClipboard::changed` while your question is about `QClipboard::selectionChanged()` ?

Comment: @MohammadKanan thanks. I fixed it. I just played with `QClipboard::changed`. It has to be `selectionChanged`

Comment: You could, instead, use work-around, by getting signal from a widget like  `QTextEdit::copyAvailable` thats emitted when you select text, see [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775668/how-can-i-replace-the-copied-text-from-qtextedit-in-my-clipboard/48777140#48777140)

Comment: The problem is I am trying to get selection outside the app, not in the widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clearly stated in [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html#selectionChanged), the `selectionChanged` signal is unavailable on Windows.

Comment: Oh, I see. I've missed the word "don't". Thanks!